# Which is more secure and why Certificate or Secret inside our Active Directory App

Tags: active-directory, azure, certificate, azure-active-directory

Inside our Azure Active Directory we have 2 options to secure our calls to the Active Directory App:-

1. Secret
2. Certificate

[image]

so which option is more secure and why? because at the end inside our applications which will be calling this App, it either need to send the client secret or the certificate thumbprint. now Microsoft already mentioned this statement:-

> For a higher level of assurance, we recommend using a certificate
> (instead of a client secret) as a credential.

but i am not sure why certificate is more secure?

Second question, if we assume that certificate is more secure, then still using a self-signed certificate consider more secure than using secret ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially asking why is certificate authentication more secure than password (secret) authentication, which has been asked many times. Check out the link to the below question, which has many answers pointing out why certificates are more secure.

[Certificate based authentication vs Username and Password authentication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/certificate-based-authentication-vs-username-and-password-authentication/3627#3627)

Microsoft state that you should only use self-signed certificates for testing purposes:

"Self-signed certificates are not trusted by default and they can be difficult to maintain. Also, they may use outdated hash and cipher suites that may not be strong. For better security, purchase a certificate signed by a well-known certificate authority."

[Create a self-signed public certificate to authenticate your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-self-signed-certificate)

I would recommend using an Azure Managed Identity instead of an app registration, wherever possible. This is more secure because it avoids having to use certificates or secrets.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so if i purchase a certificate signed by a well-known certificate authority will i get a .crt file + .pfx file + thumbprint ? similar to what we get when we generate self-signed certificate ? second question i did not use Azure Managed Identity before, as all the documentation for authorizing Azure App Functions or using asp.net core mvc web application which use Windows Identity platform for authentication will generate Azure AD apps behind the senses and not Azure Managed Identity

Comment: also what about my second question .. Second question, if we assume that certificate is more secure, then still using a self-signed certificate consider more secure than using secret ?

Comment: No, here's an article on why self-signed certificates are no good for production environments and offer no trust value: https://www.securew2.com/blog/the-dangers-of-self-signed-certificates#:~:text=The%20disadvantages%20of%20a%20self,it%20in%20the%20first%20place.

Comment: Also, you should use a certificate from a trusted authority for production instead of a secret or self-signed certificate.

Comment: Azure Managed Identity is more secure than using app registrations secured by cerficates or secrets, as mentioned in my answer. I would suggest investigating that if you're using Azure Functions which access other Azure resources.